# Substring of a variant string

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following return of a printer:

```
{Ta005000000000000000000F     00000000000000000I     00000000000000000N     00000000000000000FS    00000000000000000IS    00000000000000000NS    00000000000000000}
```

Ok, I need to save, in a list, the return in parts.

e.g.

```
[0] "Ta005000000000000000000F" 
[1] "00000000000000000I"
[2] "00000000000000000N"
...
```

The problem is that the number of characters varies.
A tried to make it going into the 'space', taking the substring, but failed...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) on a single space, and use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to make sure that multiple spaces are seen as only *one* delimiter:

```
var source = "00000000000000000FS    0000000...etc";
var myArray = source.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

@EDIT: An elegant way to get rid of the braces is to include them as separators in the `Split` (thanks to Joachim Isaksson in the comments):

```
var myArray = source.Split(new[] {' ', '{', '}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Sample: myString.Split(new[] {' ', '{', '}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); or just remove the starting/trailing braces first and split on ' '.

Comment: Much nicer. Though in the edit did you mean to get rid of the *braces* rather than spaces? I'll get rid of this if you make the edit. :)

Comment: Exact, that's exactly what I sought. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Regex for this:

```
string input = "{Ta005000000000000000000F     00000000000000000I     00000000000000000N     00000000000000000FS    00000000000000000IS    00000000000000000NS    00000000000000000}";
IEnumerable<string> matches = Regex.Matches(input, "[0-9a-zA-Z]+").Select(m => m.Value);
```

Comment: This actually feels like the cleanest solution, why'd I not think of that? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to create an array of substrings.  Split allows you to specify multiple separator characters and to ignore repeated splits if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Split member of the "String" class and split the parts up to that you want.
Sample would be:

```
string[] input = {Ta005000000000000000000F     00000000000000000I     00000000000000000N     00000000000000000FS    00000000000000000IS    00000000000000000NS    00000000000000000};
string[] splits = input.Split('     ');

Console.WriteLine(splits[0]); // Ta005000000000000000000F
```

And so on.

Comment: That code isn't valid. Your input isn't declared validly and your syntax on the split is trying to tell .net that the five spaces are a single char (by use of `'`).

Comment: Oh sorry ->
`string[] input = new string[] {Ta005000000000000000000F     00000000000000000I     00000000000000000N     00000000000000000FS    00000000000000000IS    00000000000000000NS    00000000000000000};`

Answer (score 0):

Just off the bat. Without considering the encompassing braces:

```
string printMsg = "Ta005000000000000000000F     00000000000000000I     
         00000000000000000N     00000000000000000FS    
         00000000000000000IS    00000000000000000NS    00000000000000000";
string[] msgs = printMsg.Split(' ').ForEach(s=>s.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Could work.

Comment: Did you mean select instead of ForEach there? ForEach is only on List and doesn't return anything. You'd also need a Where with a Select to remove the zero length strings.